# Strange behavior using java list in scala class

Tags: java, scala

I have scala+java project where some POJO classes written on Java, and controllers written on Scala. 
So i have an entity:

```
@Entity @Table
public class SomeEntity extends GenericEntity { 
  //... some fields
  @OneToMany(...)
  private List<SomeOtherEntity> someOtherEntities;
  // getters, setters
}
```

and the following scala code:

```
val otherEntity = // construct object of type SomeOtherEntity 
val entity = //got entity from database
entity.getSomeOtherEntities.add(otherEntity)
```

Last line produces `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException` at `java.util.AbstractList.add`. I used some debugger magic and discovered that `entity.getSomeOtherEntities` has type `Wrappers$SeqWrapper`. Is there simple scala way to add an item to java list in scala? Ofc I can construct new java.util.List and add all items to it and then use field setter in entity class, but is there a simple way?

Comment: You can change `private List<SomeOtherEntity> someOtherEntities;` to `private ArrayList<SomeOtherEntity> someOtherEntities;`.

Comment: This looks like a problem in your Java code rather than your Scala code. Have you succeeded in calling `SomeEntity#getSomeOtherEntities.add` from Java? Based on what you're saying, it looks like your Java `List` is being [properly converted to a Scala collection](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.8.2/scala/collection/JavaConversions$$SeqWrapper.html) and you're calling its `add` method correctly, but the implementation of `java.util.List` you're using doesn't support `add` (which is an optional operation according to the [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html)).

Comment: @Ben `entity.getConfigList.getClass` returns `scala.collection.convert.Wrappers$SeqWrapper`. Maybe the problem is that i use scala conversions, because same code in other places works fine.

Comment: @Everv0id that shouldn't be a problem - the usual way to work with Java collections in Scala is to implicitly wrap them. What concrete class is being used in Java to implement the `List` interface in `SomeEntity`?

Comment: If you `import collection.JavaConversions._` you can implicitly convert the `List` to a `MutableBuffer`, enabling you to do `entity.getSomeOtherEntities.append(otherEntity)` - but I suspect you'll still get the `UnsupportedOperationException`.

Comment: @Ben i use scala converters and in some place i do `asJava` on scala List. I suppose this caused problems. I'll provide more info soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved this. The problem was that I used `scala.collection.JavaConverters` and did `.asJava` on Scala `List` somewhere. My application doesn't need to be particularly speedy, so I managed to solve it by replacing setter for `SomeEntity.someOtherEntities` field with this one:

```
public void setSomeOtherEntities(List<SomeOtherEntity> someOtherEntities) {
    this.someOtherEntities = new ArrayList<>();
    this.someOtherEntities.addAll(someOtherEntities);
}
```